# Validating empty $_FILES

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I have a simple register form where the user can upload a profile picture, if the user doesn't it, it should take the default picture name called person-icon.png.

When I register an user and upload a picture it works but if i leave it blank don't do anything and that column is inserted into the DB empty

```
if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
  $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
}
else if(empty($_FILES['image']['name'])){
  $img = 'person-icon.png';
}
```

I already have tried these options:

Option 1:

```
if (empty($_FILES['image'])){
  $img = 'person-icon.png';
}
else{
  $img = $_FILES['image']['name'];
}
```

Option 2:

```
if($_FILES["image"]["error"] == 4)
```

Option 3:

```
if($_FILES["image"]["name"] == "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for $_FILE['image']['name'] not equal "" this work;
See code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html> 
<?php

//var_dump($_FILES);
$default_pic =" pic.png";
if (isset($_FILES['image'])){
    if($_FILES['image']['name'] != ""){
        echo "has pic";
    }
    else{
        $_FILES['image']['name'] = $default_pic;
        echo "has no pic";
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: @OrdepTheWizard For Securety Reasons you should check the type and the ending on the server side

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if a file has been uploaded you have to look for the `tmp_name`, because that is what contains the actual copy of your file content on the server.
I would do something like this:

```
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
if (!file_exists($file)){
  //no image
}
else{
  //image
}
```

You can also check $_FILES as long you don't upload other files in that form:

```
if(empty($_FILES)){
  //no image
}
else{
  //image
}
```

For further information check the [official manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) of file uploads.
I hope this helped you :)